# preload images before render javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanna display images instantly as all the images are loaded for my smooth slider,
but its not working.

```
var myPhotos = {
    _counter: 0,
    images: [],
    init: function() {
        ServerCall1(0, 'xml', 'rssphotos.php', function(xml) {
            imageObj = new Image();
            $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                var desc = $(this).find('description').text();
                var resp = getImgArray(desc);

                myPhotos.images[myPhotos._counter] = resp[0];
                myPhotos._counter++;

            });

            //start preloading
            for (i = 0; i < myPhotos._counter; i++) {
                imageObj.src = myPhotos.images[i];
            }

            ////PUT THE HEADER HOME PAGE
            topHeader.putData(topHeader.photoData());
        });
    }

};
```

After the execution of this function, I loop through `myPhotos.images` to get them instantly, but its rendering one by one very slowly.

Comment: You very quickly loop through all images, not waiting for each to load before you re-use the image object. That will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
var myPhotos = {
    _counter: 0,
    images: [],
    init: function() {
        ServerCall1(0, 'xml', 'rssphotos.php', function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                var desc = $(this).find('description').text();
                var resp = getImgArray(desc);

                myPhotos.images[myPhotos._counter] = resp[0];
                myPhotos._counter++;

            });

            //start preloading
            for (i = 0; i < myPhotos._counter; i++) {
                this.images[i]= new Image(); this.images[i].src = myPhotos.images[i];
            }

            ////PUT THE HEADER HOME PAGE
            topHeader.putData(topHeader.photoData());
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: thanks but now I can't access it inside jquery main function and other plugins      $(function() 
     {
  
      alert(myPhotos.images[4].src);///whole array of images is undefined
    });

Comment: Yes Its accessible inside myPhotos object everywhere and other global functions but having undefined inside jquery functions, I'm testing it again.

Comment: what I think $(function() 
 {
  celebPhotos.init();
  alert(celebPhotos._counter); }); init func is defined above but it takes more time to execute(asynchronously) and alert executes returning counter 0

Comment: That is true... It is hard to test except on your server

Comment: Thank you sir, Each time when I use myPhotos.images[index].src it send the request to get the image, can you tell me why? because once I have created a image object why it send request to server to get it and get Unmodified 304 in response, and waste time in displaying image. Can i stop it??

Comment: Hmm, I do not think you can avoid the server access unless you load a sprite (i.e. one file containing several images) and only move the view-port.